# reading values from xml file in actionscript 3 into a combobox

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, combobox

my layout in .mxml file is like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="600" height="800" >
        <fx:Declarations>
            <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        </fx:Declarations>
        <mx:HBox width="100%" horizontalAlign="right" top="20">
            <mx:ComboBox id="comboBox" fontSize="12" width="10%" dataProvider="{middleStack}"  name="versioncombo"/>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:VBox top="50" left="10" >
            <mx:Label text="Builds" fontSize="18">
            </mx:Label>
            </mx:VBox>
        <mx:VBox top="50" horizontalAlign="center" left="200">
            <mx:Label text="Date" fontSize="18">
            </mx:Label>
        </mx:VBox>
        <mx:VBox top="50" horizontalAlign="center" right="10">
            <mx:Label text="Release" fontSize="18">
            </mx:Label>
        </mx:VBox>
        <mx:VBox height="100%" width="100%" styleName="centerLightGreyBg" verticalGap="0">

            <mx:ViewStack id="middleStack" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundAlpha="0" change="changev()">
            </mx:ViewStack>

        </mx:VBox>
        <fx:Style>
```

Now I want to add values to the combo box with id = combobox and name = versioncombo by reading values from an XML File. My xml is like this.

```
<Install>
  <version>
    <number>5.0</number>
    <build>907681</build>
    <path></path>

  </version>
  <version>
    <number>6.2</number>
    <build>1043305</build>
    <path></path>

  </version>
</Install>
```

I want to populate the combo box with version number i.e 5.0,6.2.

I tried to follow this link but was not able to do it 
http://www.parorrey.com/blog/flash-development/as3-adding-dropdown-combobox-flash-component-using-actionscript-with-xml-data/

[AS3 Procedural. Randomise order of Items in Combobox From XMl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266989/as3-procedural-randomise-order-of-items-in-combobox-from-xml)

I am very new to AIR.

I tried it like this:-

```
import fl.data.DataProvider; 

            var country:String='';
            var countriesList:Array = [];

            //URLLoader class helps you to load data from an external source such as a URL

            var xmlLoader:URLLoader ; 
            var xmlData:XML = new XML(); 

            public function Pathfinding() {
                // constructor code
                xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
                xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
                xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("grid.xml"));
            }

            function LoadXML(e:Event):void { 
                xmlData = new XML(e.target.data); 
                xmlData.ignoreWhite = true;

                ParseCountries(xmlData); 
                //trace(xmlData);
            } 

            function ParseCountries(countriesInput:XML):void { 

                var countriesListing:XMLList = countriesInput.country.attributes(); 
                var i:int;  

                for each (var countryName:XML in countriesListing) { 

                    //populate the countriesList array to be used with ComboBox
                    countriesList.push( {label:countryName, data:countryName} );
                    trace(countryName);

                }

                versioncombo.prompt = "Select version:"; 
                versioncombo.dataProvider = new DataProvider(countriesList); 
                versioncombo.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, dropDownHandler);
                versioncombo.dropdown.rowHeight  = 30;
                versioncombo.width = 150;

            } 


            function dropDownHandler(event:Event):void { 

                country = ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data;     
                trace("selected country: "+ country);
                //do something here whatever you want 
            }   
comboBox.prompt = "Select Country:"; 
            comboBox.dataProvider = new DataProvider(countriesList); 
            comboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, dropDownHandler);
            comboBox.dropdown.rowHeight  = 30;
            comboBox.width = 150;
```

but was getting error "-1180: Call to a possibly undefined method DataProvider."

```
                comboBox.dataProvider = new DataProvider(countriesList);
```

not working for me.

Comment: And what's `versioncombo` ? you mean `comboBox` maybe !?

Comment: ya name of my combobox

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the `name` property with the `id` property of the `ComboBox` component you have defined. It is the `id` you need to use to refer to the `ComboBox` instance.

from [Working with Components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7ff9.html):

> You should declare an instance variable for each dynamically created
>   component and store a reference to the newly created component in it,
>   just as the MXML compiler does when you set an id property for a
>   component instance tag. You can then access your dynamically created
>   components in the same way as those declaratively created in MXML.

Comment: I tried with the id but I am getting error "1172: Definition fl.data:DataProvider could not be found"

Answer (score 1):

You are need just [read about](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstarts/using_data_providers.html) correct work with dataprovider. You didn't need a new instance creation, like "new DataProvider". Please, use **ArrayCollection** or any of **IList**